# Virtual Machine does not reconnect to LAN after Host Ethernet disconnect-reconnect

Tags: virtualbox, network-manager, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside of Oracle VirtualBox V5.2.12.
The host machine is running Windows10.
The Ethernet connection in the VM is attached to a Bridge Adapter (Intel Ethernet Connection I219-V).

Ubuntu is using the Network Manager.

When I start up the Ubuntu VM there is network connectivity to the LAN and to the Internet (via a router).  Things work as expected.

The issue is that the PC sometimes experiences an Ethernet physical disconnect-reconnect sequence but the Ubuntu VM does not try to reconnect.

In fact it looks like Ubuntu thinks Ethernet has remained connected through the entire sequence and I think this is due to the Cable Connected  check box in the Adapter configuraton menu. 
When I type ifconfig the results are the same as they were before the disconnect. However there is no connectivity from the VM to the other nodes in LAN or out to the Internet (through the router).

If I open the VM settings menu Network tab and uncheck Cable Connected I can see the desired reaction in a terminal window with "nmcli monitor" running:
**Connectivity is now 'none'
There's no primary connection
Network manager is now in the 'disconnected' state.**

When I check the Cable Connected box I see that the Network Manager rebuilds the connection:

**Network Manager is now in the 'connecting" state.**

**enp0s3: Connecting (getting IP configuration)**

**enp0s3: Using connecton 'Wired Connection 1'**

**inp0s3: connecting (starting secondary connections)**

**Connectivity is now 'full"**

**'Wired connection 1' is now the primary connection**

**Network Manager is now in the 'connected' state.**

**enp0s3: connected**

FWIW, the VM's address is a fixe IP address.  I have it set to DHCP but the router gives a fixed address to the MAC associated with the bridge connection.  I'm not sure if that helps or hurts things.

I tried using NAT as the "Attached To:" and after a disconnect-reconnect sequence I have connectivity to the LAN and Internet.  The problem is that in this mode all traffic coming from the PC has the PC's IP address.  However the application on the VM is expecting IP frames from other devices on the lan using a fixed IP address of the VM.  I also noticed that when the Ethernet cable was disconnected there was no reaction from the nmcli monitor application.

It looks like the state of the real Ethernet network is not being sent to the VM's Ethernet interface.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly that is causing the behavior I am seeing?
Is there a way to make it behave more like a real Ubuntu box behaves when it encounters an Ethernet  disconnecdt-reconnect sequence?
Thanks in advance
Jim